# Is Tech Stack knowledge important?

Tags: career-development, software-development, careers

I am working as a software developer for about 5 years. I already changed my job 5 times, so I have a little wider knowledge about the requirements of some companies, but I feel like I am still a junior, and I have to learn a lot of things about software development. On the other hand I don't want to be a "job hopper" or something like that. Currently I am working at a multinational software developer company and I think this is a very good place for me. I feel balanced and energetic (I am 25 years old), and I want to learn a lot of things.

But recently I had the recognition that I am working on a huge application with a lack of tech stack. Every part of this application is legacy and it has a solution to every single problem. My only job is to learn the parts of the application and develop the new features and fix the bugs. Sometimes it is tiring and hard, but sometimes I enjoying it. The team and the whole ecosystem of the company is very developer friendly and I like it. I like to work here, but on the other hand I am afraid about that my knowledge will become obsolete soon. E.g. I want to learn about Docker and Kubernetes, but I don't have so much time and at worktime I don't have to work with it.

Does this feeling relevant for my career? Should I find a new job again, or could I stay here for a longer time without any doubt about my tech stack knowledge?

Comment: "I am working as a software developer about ~5 years. I already changed my job 5 times [...] On the other hand I don't want to be a 'job hopper'" Bit late to be worrying about that now.

Comment: "I am working on a huge application with a lack of tech stack." Could you explain what you mean by this? Every application has a tech stack; it may be an obsolete stack or a badly defined stack, but it has a stack - you have an OS, you have a programming language (or more than one), you have some libraries in those programming languages and so on.

Comment: @PhilipKendall I read that as "lack of diversity" in the tech stack.

Comment: I'm not clear what the question here is. We can't tell you what you should or should not do, so what are you asking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tech stack is important in that it jumps you to the front of the line during the interview process when you have a specific tech stack listed in a resume and are able to articulate thoughts, processes and activities using it.

As your career progresses however, the theory and fundamentals behind the tech stacks will become even more important. So it's not so important to learn the details behind every C based language as much as it is important to learn the fundamentals and distinctions between the languages and become adaptable. Even with that in mind, it would be impossible for you to obtain that experience without becoming proficient in at least 1 of the technology options in the space.

So to put your example to the test, rather than just learning Docker/Kubernetes, it is more important that you learn the fundamentals of containerization as well as the theories behind its usefulness as well as its problems. As you're able to understand and operate within the containerization space, the tech stack itself becomes less and less relevant.